# Adding Calculated Column to List to sum values in columns while ignoring blanks

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formula

I have a questionnaire that populates a SharePoint list. There are a number of questions that return answers as picked from a choice column.

I have a calculated column that I'm trying to get to return a value as a result.
There are 4 columns that can return a string value, the formula so far will interpret these values as a numerical value. The below formula works when none of the columns are blank.

Currently it returns a sum, but the objective is to return a percentage which ignores unanswered questions. So if Col1 is blank, it is assumed the question did not apply and should not affect the %, which means I can't use  if([Col1]="High",3, if([Col1]="Med",2, if([Col1]="Low",1,0))) as a 0 value would negatively affect the percentage. I've tried a few variations of the below formula by adding in ISBLANK but these keep returning #Value! and #Name? for me.

Current Formula:

```
=SUM(
       if([Q1]="High",3, if(Q1]="Med",2, if([Q1]="Low",1)))
     , if([Q2]="High",3, if([Q2]="Med",2, if([Q2]="Low",1)))
     , if([Q3]="Often",3, if([Q3]="Monthly",2, if([Q3]="Never",1)))
     , if([Q4]="Yes",3, if([Q4]="Planned",2, if([Q4]="No",1)))
    )
```

What I would like to be able to do is divide the sum of these values by the number of questions that were not blank

Attempted formula (partial):

```
=SUM(IF(ISBLANK(Q1),"",1),IF(ISBLANK([Q2]),"",1))
```

The above returns 2 when Q1 and Q2 have answers, but when blank, it returns #Value? I assume because it is trying to add a number to a string.

Comment: Try using [COUNT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/count-function-3d28ca92-7fb1-4f08-b595-bbb4ad01ca35) which counts the number of arguments that contain numbers. Let me know it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks @GaneshSanap I was able to form a solution using CountA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [COUNT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/count-function-3d28ca92-7fb1-4f08-b595-bbb4ad01ca35) which counts the number of arguments that contain numbers.

For example:

```
=COUNT(IF(ISBLANK([Q1]),"",1),IF(ISBLANK([Q2]),"",1))
```

For other available functions, refer documentation: [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ganesh Sanap

I was able to achieve the intended result using count as per below:

```
=(SUM(
       if(
            [Q1]="High",3, 
            if(
                [Q1]="Med",2,
                if(
                    [Q1]="Low",1,0
                    )
                )
            )
     , 
        if(
            [Q2]="High",3,
            if(
                [Q2]="Med",2,
                if(
                    [Q2]="Low",1,0
                    )
                )
            )
     , 
        if(
            [Q3]="Often",3,
            if(
                [Q3]="Monthly",2,
                if(
                    [Q3]="Never",1,0
                    )
                )
            )
     ,
        if(
            [Q4]="Yes",3,
            if(
                [Q4]="Planned",2,
                if(
                    [Q4]="No",1,0
                    )
                )
            )
    )
    -
    CountA(
        [Q1],
        [Q2],
        [Q3],
        [Q4]
    )
)
/
(
    CountA(
        [Q1],
        [Q2],
        [Q3],
        [Q4]
    )
*2
)
```